# Stored Procedure error ORA-06550

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, ora-06550

I'm getting compile errors with this code using sqlplus.

My errors are:

> Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
>
> BEGIN point_triangle; END;
>
> Error at line 1: ORA-06550: Line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00905: object POINT_TRIANGLE is invalid
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL Statement ignored

Whenever I type show errors, it tells me there are no errors.

Here is the code.

```
create or replace procedure point_triangle
AS
A VARCHAR2(30);
B VARCHAR2(30);
C INT;
BEGIN
FOR thisteam in (select P.FIRSTNAME into A from PLAYERREGULARSEASON P where P.TEAM = 'IND' group by P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME order by SUM(P.PTS) DESC)
                (select P.LASTNAME into B from PLAYERREGULARSEASON P where P.TEAM = 'IND' group by P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME order by SUM(P.PTS) DESC)
                (select SUM(P.PTS) into C from PLAYERREGULARSEASON P where P.TEAM = 'IND' group by P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME order by SUM(P.PTS) DESC);
LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(A|| ' ' || B || ':' || C);
END LOOP;

END;
/
```

it is suppose to put all the players into A and B with their points of their career on that team into the C. I know the queries work, just not in the procedure.

Comment: It's a necessary element for a for-loop.

Comment: Does it need to be declared?

Comment: No, I used it earlier in my code like that for a function. Where it first shows up is where it's declared.

Comment: this cursor is invalid, the into statement should disappear and instead a FETCH statement should appear afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create or replace procedure point_triangle
AS
BEGIN
FOR thisteam in (select FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,SUM(PTS)  from PLAYERREGULARSEASON  where TEAM    = 'IND' group by FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME order by SUM(PTS) DESC)

LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(thisteam.FIRSTNAME|| ' ' || thisteam.LASTNAME || ':' || thisteam.PTS);
END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Comment: Would there be any way I could print out two different FIRSTNAMES, LASTNAME, and PTS in the same line? Like move through the list in the same iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this one:

```
create or replace 
procedure point_triangle
IS
BEGIN
  FOR thisteam in (select P.FIRSTNAME,P.LASTNAME, SUM(P.PTS) S from PLAYERREGULARSEASON P  where P.TEAM = 'IND'  group by P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME order by SUM(P.PTS) DESC)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(thisteam.FIRSTNAME|| ' ' || thisteam.LASTNAME  || ':' || thisteam.S);
  END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a semi colon at the end of the query after the closing braces, remove it and it will work:

```
FOR thisteam in (select P.FIRSTNAME into A from PLAYERREGULARSEASON P where P.TEAM = 'IND' group by P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME order by SUM(P.PTS) DESC)
            (select P.LASTNAME into B from PLAYERREGULARSEASON P where P.TEAM = 'IND' group by P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME order by SUM(P.PTS) DESC)
            (select SUM(P.PTS) into C from PLAYERREGULARSEASON P where P.TEAM = 'IND' group by P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME order by SUM(P.PTS) DESC)**;**
```